# Odoo version 8 Configuration

Tags: settings, odoo-8, accounting

I have created a field in Settings->Configuration->Accounting.

The field is default customer account. Many2one field (account_id)
I have given widget="selection" in XML.

When after clicking on Apply Button,The default customer account is present.
After any one transactions or after logout and if again loggedin , then the field I selected is empty.

Comment: Check this link https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-save-load-my-own-configuration-settings-30123

Comment: We have to use **get_param** and **set_param** default function defined in the class of **ir.config_parameter**,and pass the repective account_id in it.  It will be set in System Parameters.   It will work. It will set constantly account_id in the settings->Configuration->Accounting

Comment: it would be nice if you add an answer

Answer (score 0):

It will be resolved by **get_param** and **set_param**

**code**

from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.safe_eval import safe_eval

```
class stock_config_settings(osv.osv_memory):
    _inherit = 'stock.config.settings'

    _columns = {

    'default_stock_id' : fields.many2one('stock.location','Stock Location', required=True),

    }


    def get_default_stock(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
        icp = self.pool.get('ir.config_parameter')
        return {
            'default_stock_id': safe_eval(icp.get_param(cr, uid, 'default_stock.default_stock_id', 'False')),
        }
    def set_default_stock(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        config = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
        icp = self.pool.get('ir.config_parameter')
        icp.set_param(cr, uid, 'default_stock.default_stock_id', (config.default_stock_id.id))
```

By the above code, the value will be set properly.